# EC2 with Rubber gem - Redis/Resque FileUtils permission problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, redis, resque

I set up an EC2 instance using the Rubber gem. I'm trying to use Redis/Resque to create a zip file.  The command works fine when I run it from a Rails console, but when Redis/Resque tries it gets a permission denied error. I'm assuming that Redis/Resque is running as another user, not sure how to easily solve this – if the Rubber config could be modified to bump up the permissions or etc.... Any advice appreciated....

Comment: run the whoami command to see what user its running under

Answer (score 0):

If you're running it on the remote console, you're likely doing it with root.  Rubber starts resque workers up with the *app* user so it's a restricted account.  You need to modify the permissions for wherever you're trying to create your zip file such that the *app* user has write permissions.

Comment: How can you do this with Rubber? And another question -- should you give the app permissions to write all over the disk?

Comment: Sorry.  The permissions would either be in your local project or set up a task to modify permissions post-deploy.  E.g., config/rubber/deploy-passenger.rb does something to this effect.